# При заливке дампа в БД выдает #1100 - Table 'pma__column_info' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Заливаю в БД дамп, выдает такую ошибку:

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1100 - Table 'pma__column_info' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне решить это задачу, чтоб я не заблокировал, ненароком, не то, что нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При использовании команды LOCK TABLES необходимо блокировать все таблицы, которые предполагается использовать в последующих запросах, употребляя при этом те же самые псевдонимы, которые будут в запросах. Если таблица упоминается в запросе несколько раз (с псевдонимами), необходимо заблокировать каждый псевдоним.